# C#: Window hangs when I try to move it, click outside or minimize

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

This the picture of the application that I am trying to run:

[image]

when I try to click outside, move it, or minimize it, the window hangs:

[image]

my code:

```html
        public void Process()
    {
        //            using (HalconDotNet.HWindowControl HWinCtrl = new HalconDotNet.HWindowControl())
        //            {
        using (PitFinderEngine VisionEngine = new PitFinderEngine())
        {

            foreach (string jpegfile in JpegFiles)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] parts1 = jpegfile.Split('\\');
                    string[] parts2 = parts1[parts1.Length - 1].Split('.')[0].Split('_');
                    string row = parts2[parts2.Length - 2].Split('R')[1];
                    string col = parts2[parts2.Length - 1].Split('C')[1];
                    Results.Add(row + " " + col, VisionEngine.action(jpegfile, "Production"));
                    //FormControls.ProgressBar_DoStep();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

the "Process" is called in this manner:

```html
    public static Thread StartTheThread(string LN, string TN)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() => RealStart(LN, TN));
        t.Start();
        return t;
    }

    private static void RealStart(string ln, string tn) {
            Lots[ln].Tiles[tn].Process();

    }


    public static void DoWork()
    {
        string[] Directories = Directory.GetDirectories(LotPictureFolder);
        List<Thread> ThreadList = new List<Thread>();
        foreach (string lot in Directories)
        {
            string[] parts = lot.Split('\\');
            string LotName = parts[parts.Length - 1];
            foreach (string tile in Lots[LotName].Tiles.Keys)
            {
                if (!Lots[LotName].Tiles[tile].VicFileFound)
                {
                    ThreadList.Add(StartTheThread(LotName, tile));
                }

            }
        }

        bool AllDone = false;
        while (!AllDone)
        {
            AllDone = true;
            foreach (Thread th in ThreadList)
            {
                if (th.IsAlive)
                {
                    AllDone = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it seems that

```html
VisionEngine.action(jpegfile, "Production")
```

takes 10ms - 20ms to run and is responsible to hanging the window, if i were to move the window; meaning, that if i were to comment it off the problem will not be there, is it possible to isolate this code, I tried using threads, but the issue still persists, i cant use tasks as the platform is .Net3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you run longer tasks for you application it blocks the `UI` until the order is done. That's because your task blocks the `MainThread` for this order, so the `UI` can't respond, since it's running in the `MainThread` as well. Because the `UI` does not respond to Windows it's telling you: *Hey, watchout this window does not respond to any user actions currently.*

Even though your application does a lot of stuff in the background (what you assigned your application to do), but this does not matter for the user and Windows. The problem is that once you click more on your application, the blocked `UI`, Windows will still notice that and suggest you to close the window, because it seems like the application is stuck.

Simply use [Application.DoEvents()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) in your long running task. This behaves as the following:

> Calling this method causes the current thread to be suspended while all waiting window messages are processed.

So it pauses your currently long running task, to process the Windows messages which came from e.g. the user input, so maximizing, moving, ... the window. After that it will continue working on your long running order.

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

This implies that if e.g. your method takes 10s to complete, calling `Application.DoEvents()` once makes your application process user actions only one time, what does not seem like a behaviour you want. So you have to call it multiple times. Note that this can make your running method significantly slower.

Comment: Still not helping :(

Comment: yeah it does, sorry for not commenting

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to use a ThreadList at this point anymore. Your whole process method should start a new thread. Then make sure with events you modify the ProgressBar it's progress. Once all of that code runs on a seperate thread your UI shouldn't freeze because of that anymore.